# Tkinter text widget

Tags: python, tkinter, text-widget

I am having trouble with some code in python 3.7 involving Tkinter. I am using an online tutorial, specifically [this one](https://www.python-course.eu/tkinter_text_widget.php). I am stuck on how the END within the text widget is used. Here is my code:

```
import tkinter

GUI = tkinter.Tk()
GUI.title("Dungeon Crawler")
GUI.wm_iconbitmap('dragon.ico')
GUI.configure(background="#000000")

lbl = tkinter.Label(GUI, text="Input", fg="#fff", bg="#000000")
scribe = tkinter.Entry(GUI)
txt = tkinter.Text(GUI)

lbl.grid(row=0, column=0)
scribe.grid(row=1, column=0)
txt.grid(row=0, column=1)
txt.insert(END, "Just a text Widget\nin twolines\n")

GUI.mainloop()
```

Comment: Stuck in what way?

Comment: My mistake, I see the original question now.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have used `import tkinter` you need to do the following

```
txt.insert(tkinter.END, "Just a text Widget\nin twolines\n")
```

Rather than having to write tkinter everywhere you could change your code to import tkinter but rename it as tk.

```
import tkinter as tk
....
GUI = tk.Tk()
....
txt = tk.Text(GUI)
txt.insert(tk.END, "Just a text Widget\nin twolines\n")
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, I was able to get my code to work. I am surprised by how quickly this was answered but it was a welcome surprise.

Comment: Very welcome. It was an easy thing to spot once you've used tkinter a few times. When you can, accept/upvote the answer.

Comment: To add to this, `tkinter.END` is simply a constant containing the string `"end"`, so using this string directly also works and does not depend on the way you import tkinter.